# COBOL - Calling program

Tags: cobol

Cobol - question.
I have a written a sub-program with some procedures.
Is it possible to call this sub-program from different main programs at the same time passing all different variables.

Comment: Yes, you can CALL a program from any other program. Not sure what you mean by "all different variables". As long as the number of items and their length and type, in the order specified on the CALL ... USING ... is the same as on the PROCEDURE DIVISION USING then all will be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can call this subprogram from any main program. When you say different parameters, use USING clause to pass the corresponding values required for that particular sub program.

Comment: What do you think is a "main" program in COBOL? Does that mean you don't think you can call a subprogram from another program? When you say "values" what do you mean? What do you mean by "pass"?

Comment: Hello bill, you are correct. But we can specify calling program as a main program and called program as a sub program. This is the terminology i have used here. "Pass" means to send, "values" means variable content.

Comment: A main program is a program without any linkage section. The existence of the linkage section, in my book, means we have a callable module.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z only just noticed your comment here :-) In the IBM Mainframe world, even the first program is "called" by the operating system, and can be passed run-time parameters so can have a LINKAGE SECTION. Also a "main" program could require a LINKAGE SECTION for acquiring external storage or for loads of other reasons which don't indicate that a CALL (from COBOL) has been made. Since the distinction is meaningless (for Mainframes), I try not to make it :-). Different in other environments, and I seem to be losing out to the documentation...

Answer (score -1):

Off course you can call subprogram any time in main program. Subprogram will perform its function every time by accepting whatever parameters passed.

Comment: This is basically the same as the other answer on this not-really-a-question.